# Mysterious evil scrollbar

Tags: bug, user-interface

While compulsively checking my question, I noticed that a mysterious in-site scrollbar appeared. When I click on the scrollbar, the question disappears and I have to reload! This leads me to believe that the scrollbar is evil. I'm pretty sure this isn't intended behavior, just curious as to why this could happen.

[image]

Click on the scrollbar:

[image]

Using Chrome on Windows 8.1.

Notice the first screenshot is on Meta and the second is on the normal site. It doesn't seem to be happening on Meta anymore but still happens on the normal site.

Asaf suggested I click on the "Inspect element" menu option. While I program, I don't make websites, so I'm not sure how to interpret what I've displayed. I'll post it here.

[image]

UPDATE: Now when I reload the evil scrollbar appears, then disappears, so reproducing the bug is probably going to be hard now.

Comment: Just like Electric Light Orchestra once said "Eeeevil scrollbar (tanananana) eeeevilll scrollbar (tananana ta!) Eeeevil scroooollbaaarrrr..."; but also, can you get a screenshot?

Comment: +1 for deducing that the scrollbar is evil.

Comment: That's odd. Did you try to "inspect element" and see if there's any foul play in the computation of the CSS rules?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I added the inspect element display.

Comment: Do you happen to be zoomed in/out? `Ctrl + 0` will reset zoom to 100%.

Comment: @Oded I zoom because the screen is tiny and I see poorly.

Comment: @MattSamuel - I appreciate that - this is most likely the reason you see a scrollbar, however. The sites are not designed to be used with zoom, so scrollbars and other display issues can show up when zooming.

Comment: @Oded guess I'll just not click on it then!

Comment: So it turns out the scrollbar is a necessary evil, eh? :-)

Comment: Seems so. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Oded: "not designed to be used with zoom" is somewhat humorous - of course zoom is one of the expected issues that a professionally designed site should be designed to handle!

Comment: You have a lot of tabs.

Answer (score 5):

Using Chrome, the mysterious scroll bar appears for me when I zoom in, but only at 110% and 125%, not at 150% or 175%.

Interestingly, the same thing does not happen on math.stackexchange.com or tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The site I use the most is MSE and I've had no problems with their interface.

Comment: @Matt, Carl: Different sites have [slightly] different CSS templates (e.g. fonts, height of certain objects, etc.) which may cause this sort of discrepancy.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure it's the same Chrome bug as [reported here for comments when using SOUP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240352/horizontal-scrollbar-for-comment-container).  Basically, Chrome seems to sometimes have trouble calculating the correct content dimensions for elements with `overflow: auto`, and occasionally ends up underestimating the required size by a pixel or two, causing a useless (and somewhat broken) scroll bar to appear where no scroll bar should be.

In this particular case, I suspect that simply styling the `#content` div with `overflow: hidden` instead of `overflow: auto` should be enough to get rid of the scroll bar.  It might sometimes cause the bottom of the page to be clipped by one or two pixels on Chrome instead, but that should be completely harmless.